# How to add a button in email input?

Tags: python, html, css, django, forms

I am trying to put a button inside an email input in a Django form.

This is the code with the button next to the email input:

```
<div class="container" id="notifyEmailFormContainer">
    <form action="{% url "landing:notify_email_add" %}" method="post" id="notifyEmailForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group" id="emailInput">
               <div class="input-group-addon" id="comingSoonEmailIcon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email...." maxlength="255" required id="id_email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="addNotifyEmail()" id="submitNotifyEmail">Notify Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have a tried a couple answers in similar questions but it seems I can't get it to work.

Comment: It's a function, but I don't think it's relevant to my problem.

Comment: The button submits the form through an ajax post call to a specified url.

Comment: in this case are you using `preventDefault` to avoid a conflict with form submit ? could be relevant to add this ajax code to the question

Comment: The form works correctly. I am trying to put the button inside the email input and not next to it.

Comment: i was far away... did you try some css, like relative position ?